# Plotting contours of the paraboloid $f(x_1, x_2) = 4x_1^2+x_2^2-4x_1x_2-4x_1+2x_2+1$

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus

> I have the following function:
>   $$f(x_1, x_2) = 4x_1^2+x_2^2-4x_1x_2-4x_1+2x_2+1$$
>   and I need to plot its contours.

**My Attempt**

I recognized this is  a conic section given in its [Cartesian form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#General_Cartesian_form):
$$Ax^{2}+Bxy+Cy^{2}+Dx+Ey+F=0$$
Since $B^2-4AC=16 - 4\times 4 = 0$ we [know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Discriminant) this is a parabola.
 Looking at the [General Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#General_case) of a parabola, I rewrite the contours in this way:

$$4x_1^2+x_2^2-4x_1x_2-4x_1+2x_2+1=C \quad \quad \text{for } C\in\mathbb{R} $$
$$x_2^2+2x_2(1-2x_1) + 4x_1^2-4x_1+1 - C = 0$$
$$(x_2 + (1-2x_1))^2 - C = 0$$
This would mean that 
$$x_2 + 1 - 2x_1 = 0$$
is the directrix of the parabola, i.e. $x_2 = 2x_1 - 1$. Here's a plot of that:
[image: contour]

However, I have no idea how to proceed from here. I am not even sure that what I've done makes sense, to be honest.

Comment: Well, I would first ask Wolfram Alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+4x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+-4xy+-+4x+%2B+2y+%2B1

Comment: Wolfram Alpha tells that (replacing $x_1 = y$ and $x_2=y$) the equation is equal to
$$
f = (2x-y-1)^2
$$
So therefore, if you set $f=\text{constant} \Rightarrow (2x-y-1) =  \sqrt{\text{constant}} = \text{constant}$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(x_2 + (1-2x_1))^2 - C = 0$ is correct and makes sense. From here, if $C>0$ we get two lines taking along them the same value $C$ for $f$, $r_1:x_2 + (1-2x_1)=\sqrt{C}$ and $r_2:x_2 + (1-2x_1)=-\sqrt{C}$ When $C=0$ there is only one line and if $C<0$ there are no solutions as $f$ does not reach negative values. Cutting the surface with a plane perpendicular to these lines $2x_2+x_1=K$ ($z$ any) we get the profile of a parabola.

The plot must consist mostly in two parallel lines.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the discriminant, you also have to examine the full $3\times3$ determinant of the matrix of this family of conics. It turns out to vanish identically, so the level curves are all *degenerate*: they are pairs of parallel (or coincident) lines.

Comment: I think you can show that the 3 by 3 determinant is just -4 times the discriminant, so that if the discriminant is zero, also the determinant is zero

Comment: @Euler_Salter That’s not at all true for a general conic section. The discriminant only involves the quadratic part of the equation—it’s a multiple of the principal $2\times2$ minor of the matrix. Compare the discriminants and full determinants of $y^2=x$ or $x^2=y^2$, for instance. For the former, the discriminant vanishes, but the $3\times3$ determinant doesn’t, and vice-versa for the latter.